# How to add a bolt into my unity project

Tags: unity

In my game, one of the character you pick as a special ability called the dash. It allows the player to quickly move forward. Included below is the code. It just throws up a bunch of errors. This is a 3d scene

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.KeyDirection * 260 * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }

        }
    }
```
````

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: What are your errors?

Answer (score 1):

**Vector3** does not have a **keyDirection** property, so that is the main error.

Replace this code in your Update method:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
{
    transform.Translate(0.1f,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and thanks for reminding me to add that information, but this scene is 3d

Comment: @jackson no matter it work in 3d too

Comment: I tossed it in, and I am getting an error. It is below

Assets\Scripts\PlayerBolt.cs(18,33): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'

Comment: @jackson you know what is autocomplete? that was my typing error. just put you cursor on error with red underline and press ctrl+space to give you fix list. please get enough c# knowledge before learning unity. that is much faster.

Comment: Visual Studio says there are no errors

Comment: @jackson it means visual studio is no synced with unity

Comment: Alright, I don't know how to sync them, all I want to know is what is cause the error. I have been looking at articles for a while, and none of the fixes provided work correctly

Comment: @jackson Replace 0 with 0f to make clear to the compiler that you mean the float value of 0, not the integer or double. Yes, it's a bit annoying that C# can't do that conversion automatically, but you get used to it.